# How to use data-display with multiple inputs?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form wizard, in the last step I want display a preview of the form data submitted. I'm using data-display attribute to do that. I have multiple inputs with same name:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control input_nb" name="num_espece[]" placeholder="Indiquer le nombre">
```

and this is how I display in the final step:

```
<p class="form-control-static display-value" data-display="num_espece[]"></p>
```

and this is the script used for that:

```
 f = function() {

        $(".display-value", form).each(function() {

            var a = $('[name="' + $(this).attr("data-display") + '"]', form);

            "text" == a.attr("type") || "email" == a.attr("type") || a.is("textarea") ? $(this).html(a.val()) : a.is("select") ? $(this).html(a.find("option:selected").text()) : a.is(":radio") || a.is(":checkbox") ? $(this).html(a.filter(":checked").closest("label").text()) : "card_expiry" == $(this).attr("data-display") && $(this).html($('[name="card_expiry_mm"]', form).val() + "/" + $('[name="card_expiry_yyyy"]', form).val())

        })

    },
```

When I'm in the preview step I get only the value of the first input displayed. What should I do to get the values of all inputs displayed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly you want to add all input values into **one** `<p>` tag, right?

Right now you iterate over all `<p class="display-value">` tags and then find all elements with the same name provided in the `data-display` attribute. Your `var a` now contains a list of elements but in your code you treat it as a single element. You need to loop over all fields and append the values to the display element, `$(this).html(...)` will overwrite it so you want to append the text via `$(this).append(...)`.

**Code sample**

```
f = function() {
  var form = $("form");

  $(".display-value").each(function() {
    $(this).html('');
    var as = $('[name="' + $(this).data("display") + '"]');
    if (as && as.length) {
      for (var i = 0; i < as.length; i++) {
        var a = $(as[i]);
        "text" == a.attr("type") ||
        "email" == a.attr("type") ||
        a.is("textarea")
          ? $(this).append(a.val())
          : a.is("select")
            ? $(this).append(a.find("option:selected").text())
            : a.is(":radio") || a.is(":checkbox")
              ? $(this).append(
                  a
                    .filter(":checked")
                    .closest("label")
                    .text()
                )
              : "card_expiry" == $(this).attr("data-display") &&
                $(this).append(
                  $('[name="card_expiry_mm"]', form).val() +
                    "/" +
                    $('[name="card_expiry_yyyy"]', form).val()
                );
      }
    }
  });
};
```

A demo can be found in this [Codepen](https://codepen.io/AlexWayhill/pen/agOgLR).

Answer (score 1):

Welcome Youssef, if I understood you well, you want everything inside your `form` to be shown after `submit`

Let's suppose this is your `form`

```
<form>
  <input placeholder="Your name" required>
  <input type="email" placeholder="Your email" required>
  <textarea placeholder="Your comment"></textarea>
  <button>Check</button>
</form>
```

You just need to get all items and show their values.

```
// Avoid submit button
const $items = document.querySelectorAll('form > *:not(button)')

// On submit
document.querySelector('form').onsubmit = e => {
  // Show all data
  document.body.innerHTML = [...$items].reduce((acc, e) => 
  acc += `${e.placeholder} = ${e.value}<br>`, '')
  // Aborting real submit, this is just an example
  e.preventDefault()
}
```

Instead of `document.body` you can use `document.querySelector('p.display-value')`
https://jsfiddle.net/3mc29vyj/

Hope this help or at least point you to the right direction : )